# How do I make my partitions show up in MyComputer in Ubuntu?

Tags: partitioning, nautilus

My partition setup is like this

```
Location  - Partition Label
/dev/sda5 - root
/dev/sda6 - home
/dev/sda7 - work_partition
/dev/sda8 - play_partition
```

I am not able to find the location of MyComputer in ubuntu.

Right now I can only see the `root` folder in MyComputer.

I have mounted the `work_partition` and `play_partition` on `/mnt/` and it shows up there everytime, even if I reboot the machine. But, I want it to show up on MyComputer next to the root folder.

So how do I make my partitions show up ?

Comment: You could bookmark the folders where the partitions are mounted in the file manager to make it easier to access them. That option in Nautilus is somewhere in the menus (don't know where in 12.04) and the keyboard shortcut should be `Ctrl+D`.

Comment: @BrunoNova in 12.04 the "Add Bookmark" option is in the menu under "Bookmarks" the first 2 options are "Add Bookmark" and "Edit bookmarks"  (and the shortcut *is* `Ctrl+D` for add)

Comment: @TrailRider Thanks for the info! I'm using 13.10, so those options are in a completely different place. :)

Comment: I want it to be on the main screen instead on the sidebar. That is why "bookmark" option is not possible. Does anyone know the location of the "Computer" icon, that way I can create a link from /mnt/ to that location.

Answer (score 1):

I ended up creating separate NTFS filesystem partitions for work_partition(Work Folders) and play_partition(Multimedia).

This shows up in the side bar of Nautilus file manager like in bookmarks but under devices sub-menu, which is more readable and better organized the way I want it.

And also has the advantages of being usable by Microsoft Windows 7,8 or any other windows I might have , Since I dual boot my personal machine most of the time.

The only caveat is that I might have to click on the partitions to mount them every time I want to use them. But I think there is an option to auto-mount them every time the Ubuntu OS boots up. But not sure if it will affect performance of cpu and battery, if all the partitions are mounted up, even though I might or might not use them.

Hope this is of use to other people.
Suggestions and tips to improve will be greatly appreciated.
Thanks for your suggestions mates.